# What is the correct term for when a web browser auto-adjusts vertical scrolling depending on webpage content?

Tags: firefox, browser, scrolling, user-interface, ux

What is the correct term for when a web browser auto-adjusts vertical scrolling depending on webpage content?

This feature is supposed to help with viewing webpages, but I would like to try turning it off in Firefox (desktop version).  I just can't recall what the correct term is so I can find the preference (setting) to disable.

I was asked for more details, and I'll do my best: When a modern webpage renders in a web browser, not all the elements are initially available.  This is because, often, elements like images and iframes are stored in separate files on the server than the page's main HTML.  So as more and more of the elements of a webpage are downloaded from the server, the scroll position may need to be changed so that the elements shown in the viewport remain consistent.

Firefox recently (within the last year) made significant advances in their algorithms to show the user a consistent area of the webpage as different elements are downloaded and rendered from the web server.

But I think an extension I'm using (perhaps the `Dark Reader` web extension) may be interfering with Firefox's logic, causing the vertical scrolling to be *["herky-jerky"](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/herky-jerky)* as web page elements are download from the server and are rendered by the browser.  As such, I would like to experiment with disabling this functionality, but I can't recall the correct term for this optimization to perform a search for the appropriate setting.

I hope that helps clarify!

What's the correct term for this functionality (or if you know the Firefox preference, you can provide it and save me a step, but I wanted to write this question in a manner to possibly generate a faster answer)?

Comment: I don't know what feature or behaviour you are describing. Any chance you can elaborate on what actually happens?

Comment: @Mokubai Yes, and I wish I could recall the correct the term, because then I'm sure you would know what I'm talking about... but then again, that's the whole point of my question. :)  :)  :)   I'll edit the question now to try to add more details that may help.

Comment: @Mokubai Okay, I added more details.  I hope people still read the question!  I've noticed that long questions often go unread and unanswered, so I've learned to try to be as succinct as possible but still provide sufficient details to hopefully get a quality answer.  I think, as you noted, I went a little thin on the details for this one, especially since most people not even be aware of this valuable behind-the-scenes functionality in Firefox.

Comment: Do you have any examples of webpages with the behaviour you are seeing? Perhaps recording a small section of the page as a gif using [licecap](https://www.cockos.com/licecap/) might let us see the problem more clearly. Long questions may indeed "put people off", but conversely questions with too little *real* information on what the problem you are trying to solve put people off as well. I want to help, but I have no idea how to reproduce your problem. If you suspect Dark Reader of causing performance issues (I saw significant issues especially on mobile) then have you tried disabling it?

Comment: @Mokubai Thanks.  I agree with everything you wrote.  Regarding disabling Dark Reader, I was going the other direction (tweaking the browser) since Dark Reader is currently an important extension for me.  (BTW, I just realized I didn't specify "Desktop" anywhere, as opposed to mobile, so I'll add that essential detail too.)